# My code that checks if a given number is palindrome or not doesn't work

Tags: python, palindrome

```
var1 = int(input("enter a number:"))
num = str(var1)[::-1]

if var1 == num:
    print("its a palindrome")
else:
    print("its not a palindrome")
```

`enter a number:121`   ---> expected "its a palindrome"

`its not a palindrome`

`enter a number:123`
`its not a palindrome`

Why doesn't the code work in the first example?

Answer (score 0):

While comparing, convert var1 to string:

```
var1 = int(input("enter a number:"))
num = str(var1)[::-1]

if str(var1) == num:
    print("its a palindrome")
else:
    print("its not a palindrome")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

1. Convert the number to string format using str() function.
2. Using string slicing, reverse the number.
3. Check if the reversed number matches the original number.

```
num = int(input("Enter number : " ))
reverse = int(str(num)[::-1])

if num == reverse:
   print("Palindrome")
else:
   print("Not Palindrome")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable types are not the same:

```
var1 = int(input("enter a number:"))
num = str(var1)[::-1]
var2 = int(num)

if var1 == var2:
    print("its a palindrome")
else:
    print("its not a palindrome")
```

you need convert to integer type, or:

```
var1 = input("enter a number:")
var2 = var1[::-1]
if var1 == var2:
    print("its a palindrome")
else:
    print("its not a palindrome")
```